# MongoDB ECONNRESET error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, hapi.js, econnreset

I'm trying to setup a basic mongodb connection, but I get an `ECONNRESET` error. I've researched a bit and found similar questions and answers but haven't found a solution.

**Code:**

```
'use strict';

const Hapi = require('hapi');
const hapiMongo = require('hapi-mongodb');

var server = new Hapi.Server();
server.connection({
  port: '1111'
});

server.route({
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/',
  config: {
    cors: true,
    handler: (request, reply) => {
      var db = request.server.plugins['hapi-mongodb'].db;
      reply('Hello World' + db);
    }
  }
});

server.register({
  register: hapiMongo,
  options: {
    "url": "mongodb://username:psswd@ds011308.mongolab.com:11308/heroku_jg542kf4",
    "settings": {
      "db": {
        "native_parser": false
      }
    }
  }
}, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    throw err;
  }
  server.start((err) => console.log('Served at:', server.info.uri));
})
```

**Console error:**

> { [MongoError: server ds011308-a.mongolab.com:11308 received an error
>   {"name":"M ongoError","message":"read ECONNRESET"}]   name:
>   'MongoError',   message: 'server ds011308-a.mongolab.com:11308
>   received an error {"name":"Mong oError","message":"read ECONNRESET"}'
>   }
>
> C:\Users\username\Desktop\code\hapi-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:4
>   54
>                 throw err
>                 ^  MongoError: server ds011308-a.mongolab.com:11308 received an error {"name":"Mon goError","message":"read ECONNRESET"}
>       at null. (C:\Users\username\Desktop\code\hapi-mongo\node_modules\mong
>   odb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:297:40)
>       at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
>       at emit (events.js:172:7)
>       at null. (C:\Users\username\Desktop\code\hapi-mongo\node_modules\mong
>   odb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:132:12)
>       at g (events.js:260:16)
>       at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
>       at emit (events.js:172:7)
>       at Socket. (C:\Users\username\Desktop\code\hapi-mongo\node_modules\mo
>   ngodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:132:49)
>       at Socket.g (events.js:260:16)
>       at emitOne (events.js:77:13)

Any pointers on how I can fix this?

Comment: I have similar usage here: https://github.com/adrianblynch/hapi-everything/blob/master/index.js

Comment: Can you connect to Mongo via other means?